# Set origin to top-left corner of screen in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android app with OpenGL ES 2.0. It consists of a 2D HUD overlaid on a 3D scene. Everything is fine with the 3D part, but I cannot figure out **how to position the origin at the top-left corner of the screen** (with the y-axis pointing down) when drawing in 2D. Right now I have the origin at the center of the screen and I am just subtracting half the width and height from the coordinates as I draw. (I know this is a hacky solution and I want to fix this!)

**Here is the relevant code:**

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, -width / 2, width / 2, height / 2, -height / 2, -1, 1);
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
```

**Here are the relevant shaders:**

```
private final static String vertexShaderCode =
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec2 aTexCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +
                "attribute vec4 aColor;" +
                "varying vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  vColor = aColor;" +
                "  vTexCoordinate = aTexCoordinate;" +
                "  gl_Position = aPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
                "}";

private final static String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);" +
                "}";
```

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried using this line instead:

  ```
  Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, 0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
  ```
- I have tried positioning the origin at the bottom-left, not the top-left (I shouldn't be doing this but I tried anyway).
- I have tried switching the order of `aPosition` and `uMVPMatrix` in the second-to-last line of the vertex shader.

No combination of these three changes solved the problem for me (the 2D objects do not render).

The other thing I tried was setting the origin to be one pixel off center, then two, then three, etc. The images kept getting skewed the more I moved off center, eventually becoming too thin to be visible -- but that still doesn't tell me how to fix this.

**So again, the question is:** how do I position the origin at the top-left in OpenGL ES 2.0?

P.S. My contract (first job!) ends on July 29 so I need an answer pretty soon; I don't want to leave the next people with a hacky fix like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not a rule have only one mvpMatrix in OpenGL. It is good because you can customize a lot of views.

If all of your application is based in mvpMatrix that you showed here, I recommend you create another mvpMatrix for the proposal that you are asking: Make the center of the view in top-left corner.

So, the answer is simple, lets recreate every matrix.  At first, viewMatrix:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 
     0, 0,  6,   //eye
     0, 0,  0,   //center
     0, 1,  0);  //UP *remove your -1
```

The magic is below. You have to invert bottom and top:

```
float screenRatio = (float) width / height;
Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, 
        0, screenRatio, // left, right
        1, 0,           // bottom, top        <----Solution is invert bottom with top
        -1, 10);        // near, far
```

And finally:

```
    Matrix.multiplyMM(
            viewProjectionMatrix, 0, 
            projectionMatrix, 0, 
            viewMatrix, 0);
```

P.S: don't need to change `GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);`

OpenGL have a lot of solution for this problem, because you can handle all matrix as you can.

Another solution is to customize your own matrix, without using `Matrix.orthoM(..)` or `Matrix.frustum(..)`:

```
public static final float[] topLeftMatrix(int width, int height){
    float matrix[] = new float[16];

    // This is inverse of viewPort matrix
    matrix[0] = 2.0f/width;
    matrix[1] = 0;
    matrix[2] = 0;
    matrix[3] = 0;

    matrix[4] = 0;
    matrix[5] = -2.0f/height;
    matrix[6] = 0;
    matrix[7] = 0;

    matrix[8] = 0;
    matrix[9] = 0;
    matrix[10] = 1;
    matrix[11] = 0;

    matrix[12] = -1;
    matrix[13] = 1;
    matrix[14] = 0;
    matrix[15] = 1;

    return matrix;
}
```

This matrix above is good for handling objects over pixels (like user-interface).

For full understanding, I recommend you read this article: [3D Graphics with OpenGL](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/cg_basicstheory.html). It helped me a lot to understand the opengl magic.

P.S: there is an error in your shader. The correct way to multiply matrix4x4 by a vector 4x1 is:

`gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;`

Comment: I will try this when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: As for the last point you made about the shader, it makes sense (this is how I do it in 3D). Strangely, in 2D `vector * matrix` works but `matrix * vector` doesn't (at least I couldn't get it to).

Comment: OpenGL work with math rules. So you can only multiply matrices that the number of columns is the same as the number of the line. [Matrix-Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))

Comment: Yeah I know how to multiply matrices, and so I find it very peculiar that this works for me. I had been thinking that the centered origin created a special case where drawing is correct with the multiplication reversed. But as I said in the question, using the correct order didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried yet because I have something else I'm doing at work. It'll probably be Monday or Tuesday before I get a chance. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.