# Render a 3D Object off the Center of the screen: ARTOOLKIT ANDROID

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Hi I am working on a AR android app. I am using ARToolkit6. In this app I want to view my 3D object( A Cube) on left half of the screen. With this eventually I want to display 3 cubes on the screen each on 1/3 of the screen area.

I was able to scale the 3D object by tweaking ModelView Matrix. What I read so far, I think I need to tweak projection matrix to achieve my goal. I tried looking solutions online. But Couldn't get it to work. Can anyone direct me to right path?

```
for (int trackableUID : trackableUIDs) {
        // If the marker is visible, apply its transformation, and render a cube
        if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(trackableUID)) {
            float[] projectionMatrix = ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix();
            float[] modelViewMatrix = ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(trackableUID);

            float[] scalingMat = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0, 1};
            float[] newModelView = modelViewMatrix;
            multiplyMM(newModelView, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0, scalingMat, 0);

            cube.draw(projectionMatrix, newModelView);
}
```

I followed the this link [Set origin to top-left corner of screen in OpenGL ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416820/set-origin-to-top-left-corner-of-screen-in-opengl-es-2) and  [(OpenGL ES) Objects away from view centre are stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457210/opengl-es-objects-away-from-view-centre-are-stretched).   So I translated the modelView Matrix but it doesn't solve the problem, the 3D object appears at the center of the screen. Can you explain how should I approach this problem? Thanks

@Override
public void draw() {
    super.draw();

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);

// Look for trackables, and draw on each found one.
for (int trackableUID : trackableUIDs) {
    // If the marker is visible, apply its transformation, and render a cube
    if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(trackableUID)) {
        float[] projectionMatrix = ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix();
        float[] modelViewMatrix = ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(trackableUID);

        float[] scalingMat = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0, 1};

        multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, scalingMat, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

        float[] rightModelMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(rightModelMatrix, 0);
        // Translate outer sphere by 5 in x.
        Matrix.translateM(rightModelMatrix, 0, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, rightModelMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

        cube.draw(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);



    }
}
```

Also tried this but the object gets displayed at the center of the screen.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glTranslatef(5f, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: What result are you getting now and how is it different from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you please help? Direct me to correct path or something to read?